# I think it's a manhood thing

Tags: phrase-request, idiomatic-language

> I always wanted to buy a 4*4 car because it's safer and stronger. I
>   think it's a manhood thing.

I mean that men usually like big and strong things as it's part of their childish nature, and I'm not sure whether I used this expression correctly and I wonder whether it is normal and appropriate expression. I don't want to find myself in a very embarrassing situation.

Comment: It's OK, but 'it's a man thing' would work just as well. Note that 'manhood' can mean 'penis'. A 'manhood thing' in the context of male anxiety or status can be interpreted by a listener to refer to penis size. Cars perceived to be chosen by men to show off are sometimes called 'penis extensions'. A 'man thing' is more general and linked to thoughts about gender role.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your example sentence

> I always wanted to buy a 4x4 car because it's safer and stronger. I think it's a **manhood** thing.

**Manhood** is not quite the expression to use, as @MichaelHarvey points out it could be interpreted to mean a specific part of a male's anatomy.

The usual expression is:

> It's a **guy** thing.

Meaning it's mainly associated with "**guys**" which is a more idomatic expression, you could also say

> It's a **male** thing

Which definitively draws the line based on gender. But using "**guy**" has other connotations: drinking beer, hunting, poker, chasing women which are generally things that "**guys**" do.

Comment: I disagree that 'it's a **guy** thing' is **the** usual expression. It may be so in dialect zones where 'guy' is the dominant informal term for 'man', if there are such zones.

Comment: I am not a native English speaker but I think guy is very common in America. I prefer to use man because it sounds more formal.